# Cannot unset schg flag on M1 Mac

Tags: symlink, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am using a Mac mini with M1. I created a symlink on the Desktop folder and set `schg` flag so that the system would not cancel the link.

Now I want to revert Desktop back to a normal folder, but the flag cannot be removed with this command:

```
sudo chflags noschg [path]
```

For Intel-based Macs, booting in Single User Mode is advised for removing this specific flag since the system cannot alter a folder when `schg` is set. But there is no longer Single User Mode in M1 Macs. I tried removing the flag in Recovery mode with the same command but it didn't help.

What is the correct way to unset schg flag in M1 Macs?

Answer (score 2):

Found [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115632?answerId=356962022#356962022) which actually works:

```
sudo chflags -hv noschg [Path]
```

e.g. in my case (`~/Desktop` symlinked to `~/Dropbox/Desktop`)

```
sudo chflags -hv noschg ~/Desktop
```

Per man page

```
     -h      If the file is a symbolic link, change the file flags of the link itself rather than
             the file to which it points.
```

And `-v` is just verbose.

Comment: I had trouble in uninstalling the app FortiClient, which was locked, but the standard ways of unlocking were somehow disabled. I found that the app had the `schg` flag. The command above just worked and subsequently I was able to unlock the app and uninstall/remove it by `sudo rm -r folderpath`. Thanks!